# Woocommerce Selector de atributos de producto

Tags: woocommerce, atributos

En la lista de atributos de los productos se me ha activado un indicar de posición para realizar la selección, lo cual le quita vistosidad a la pagina, He intentado quitarlo pero no consigo como.

[image: Selector de Atributo del Producto]